# Why parent router is activated when navigating through child routes?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a simple application with nested router-outlet and my question is how can i disable "re-initialization" of the parent router-outlet while navigating child routes inside?

Right now I am animating my page changes (inside the custom router-outlet) but even when I am navigating through child pages my root page gets animated and it looks weird.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement [CanReuse](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/CanReuse-interface.html)

by adding

```
routerCanReuse(next: ComponentInstruction, prev: ComponentInstruction) { return true; }
```

You tell Angular to reuse the component when the route is updated (doesn't work if you route away from the component and back again.

Comment: thank you :) it works, i have moved everything to custom router-outlet class and now it works as i wanted :)